# How to rotate a projected image 90 degrees

Tags: lateral-thinking

In film school, I wanted to project a film of mine in portrait (vertical) orientation rather than landscape (horizontal) orientation. However, my film professor told me that the projector couldn't be tipped on its side; oil in parts of the projector would drip over the film and onto the light, possibly making it explode.

How did I rotate the projected image 90 degrees without tipping the film projector?

[image]

HINT:

> I used 2 flat mirrors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a way I think would work.

> Use a mirror at about a 45 degree angle in front of the projector that redirects the light up. Then use another one that intercept that projection at a 45 degree angle and redirect it to the left. The end image will be projected on the left of the projector, not in the front like usual.

Comment: Exactly! It took me months to figure that out. Nicely done!

Comment: @CreatedByBrett thanks. I haven't had physics class for over 10 years, but I really like it. I had to close my eyes and imagine your smiley face drawing rebound on mirrors in my mind for a while before I got the correct directions XD

Comment: @CreatedByBrett Oddly, took me just several seconds to solve this, even though other riddles around here seem impossible to me.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy That's surprising! You must have exceptional spatial reasoning skills.